# How I can sort the data with array in php?

Tags: php, sql, arrays

In postman,

I post the array like

[image]

```
key => Image[] / value => 1
key => Image[] / value => 2
key => Image[] / value => 3
```

I want when I put an array which user's card images, receive the card's Idx and Name.

So I make query like this,

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT
                    Idx AS Idx, 
                    Name AS Name 
                    FROM Card
                    WHERE Card.Image IN ('$_POST[Image]')";
```

But, It receive no data.
So I remove '' so

```
WHERE Card.Image IN ('$_POST[Image]')" 
=> WHERE Card.Image IN ($_POST[Image])";
```

Then return Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'

I don't know what is problem of this.

when I post array like /key name[]/value 1
I know it can receive $_POST[name].

How I can post array and receive of it.

Please help me.

Comment: add your post code. It seems that you aren't posting the images correctly. To set more than one file/image at the same time you'll need a preventdefault and an ajax function and insert one by one (this is the best secure and reliable option).

Comment: `Card.Image`-> is `Image` column  have numbers?

Comment: @JoelBonetR I just using postman so I don't add this but add the picture

Comment: oh ok then, it's ok

Comment: @PolarisNation  did you checked my last edited answer. please check and try and let me know worked or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope `Image` column contains numbers.

Use `implode()` to correct your `IN` query

```
$string=$_POST['Image'];
$array= implode(',', $string);
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT Idx AS Idx, Name AS Name FROM Card WHERE Card.Image IN ($array)";
```

***Note:-***

1.Query will become:-`SELECT DISTINCT Idx AS Idx, Name AS Name FROM Card WHERE Card.Image IN (1,2,3)`. Now it will execute fine.

2.Try to use ***`prepared statements`*** of ***`mysqli_*`*** or ***`PDO`*** to prevent your code from ***`SQL-INJECTION`***. You current code is wide-open for it.

Comment: Thanks  you saved my time. the solution was settled.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string=$_POST[Image];
$array=array_map('intval', explode(',', $string));
$array = implode("','",$array);
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT Idx AS Idx, Name AS Name FROM Card WHERE 
           Card.Image IN ('".$array."')";
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: I try this code but could not get any response of it